# MVVM binding to multiple viewvmodels

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light

Can I quickly confirm if this is a best practice or I should be rethinking my process with MVVM. (I am new to this)

```
<ComboBox  DataContext="{Binding MemberMain, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" ItemsSource="{Binding PayMethodList}" Text="{Binding DataContext.Member.MM_PaymentMethod, ElementName=TabItemClient}"  Margin="0,0,15,0"/>
```

I am binding a combobox itemssource to one view model and the text to another.
Thanks in advance Scott

Comment: The ViewModel should contain all the information you need to bind to. It is your abstraction layer. It is not your concern where the actual data comes from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing glaring that I see here is the DataContext binding. Do you really need this?

Other than that. If it works and remains concise, if you can swap bits in/out with little issue, then it is fine.

Posting your view model may help further assessment.

Comment: I have a remodeled tab control and am using a view-model per page of that tab control that's why I have referring to a different view-model with that tab. Each page has this combo on it i.e. one for a filter and one for an actual field in the database. Just wanted to make sure the crossover between made sense. thanks for your answer. it helps